# Is it possible to get CPTBarPlot's tip point value(CGPoint value)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-plot

In the Vertical bar chart, I am using 1 or 2 plots to draw a CPTBarPlot. Now when user tap on on that BarPlot, I want to retrieve tip point of that CPTBarPlot in CGPoint value. Can anyone help on this?

Thank you.

Naveen Thunga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is delegate method to find out which bar has been selected and its bar value.did you try

> -(void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;